# Spark executor out of memory on join

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, pyspark, cluster-computing

Hi I am using spark Mllib and doing approxSimilarityJoin between a 1M dataset and a 1k dataset.
When i do it I bradcast the 1k one.
What I see is that thew job stops going forward at the second-last task.
All the executors are dead but one which keeps running for very long time until it reaches Out of memory.
I checked ganglia and it shows memory keeping rising until it reaches the limit
[image]

and the disk space keeps going down until it finishes:
[image]
The action I called is a write, but it does the same with count.
Now I wonder: is it possible that all the partitions in the cluster converge to only one node and creating this bottleneck?

Here is my code snippet:

```scala
var dfW = cookesWb.withColumn("n", monotonically_increasing_id())
    var bunchDf = dfW.filter(col("n").geq(0) && col("n").lt(1000000) )
    bunchDf.repartition(3000)
    model.
    approxSimilarityJoin(bunchDf,broadcast(cookesNextLimited),80,"EuclideanDistance").
    withColumn("min_distance", min(col("EuclideanDistance")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("datasetA.uid")))
                  ).
        filter(col("EuclideanDistance") === col("min_distance")).
      select(col("datasetA.uid").alias("weboId"),
        col("datasetB.nextploraId").alias("nextId"),
        col("EuclideanDistance")).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("approxJoin.parquet")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer as best as I can.
In Spark there are things that are called shuffle operations, and they do exactly what you thought , after some calculations they transfer all the information to a single node. 
If you think about it there's no other way for those operations to work without putting all the data in a single node in the end.

example for join operation:
you have to partitions on 2 different nodes

```
partition 1:
s, 1
partition 2:
s, k
```

and you want to join by the s. 
If you dont get both rows on a single machine it will be impossible to calculate they need to be joined.

It is the same with count and reduce and many more operations.
You can read about shuffle operations or ask me if you want more clarification.

a possible solution for you is :
instead of only saving data in memory you can use something like :

```
dfW.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

there are other options for persist but what it does basically is saving the partitions and data not only in memory but in disk as well in a Serialized way to save space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, During my operation I am not caching anything. Do you think it is good to persist in memory before calling the join? Doesn't spark automatically menages the persistence if the memory is exceeded ?

Comment: It will automatically will try to use just memory which is why you get out of memory error, by the persist command I showed, you tell spark to save the data in disk as well , and save space by using serialization storing.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I try. Do you think a 10 machines cluster with 30GB memory each and 150GB disk is enough for this kind of operation? Thanks

Comment: It really depends , 1 million rows * 1000 rows is 1 Billions rows
if all that data cant fit then the answer is probably no, maybe you can do something smarter then a join operation.

Comment: I tried but it keeps getting stuck. I think I should increase cluster size, or machines. Do you recomend to tune any spark property in particular?

Comment: Try and tell me what you are trying to do, probably there is a better option then a join.

Comment: I am using spark MlLib using the approxSimilarityJoin, which creates hashes of each row, calculates the euclidean distance between the rows and finds the most similar ones according to a threshold.  The problem is when I call this function, which does all the job. I checked the code under the hood and it does a join

Comment: You probably shouldnt even use spark MLib , you can read about it online but spark is moving away from creating ml libs and into wrapping existing ML libs like tensorflow. the ML libs by spark are really bad , there are alot of benchmarks about it online if you look.

Comment: What do you recommend to use for big datainstead? Apache Mahout?